# I am trying to get my GUI to receive messages from another application. However, nothing works

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, networkstream

As the title says, I have been given a simple flight simulator and I have been tasked to create a GUI which connects to the flight sim (Through Socket Programming). Then I can send Control Updates to the flight sim through a button by using TCPClient and writing to the stream (already done that).

However, the flight Sim I have been given sends telemetry information and my GUI is supposed to receive that information and display it on a datagridView. I have tried running a thread in the background to invoke the ReceiveMessage method and then the DisplayMessage method is supposed to activate but nothing works. The Flight Simulator sends a JSON string and from what I understood, my GUI needs to deserialize it and present it on to the Data Grid View.

Sorry if my explanation is not great. Here is the code: 
The process of listening when the programs are connected should work in the following sequence:

```
public void ConnectProgram(string IPaddress, int port)
        {            
            tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            tcpClient.Connect(IPaddress, port);
        }
```

```
private void start()
        {
            messageInThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessage))
            {
                IsBackground = true
            };
            //thank you LarsTech for pointing out to write .Start() but it still doesn't work
            messageInThread.Start();
            btnListen.Enabled = false;
        }
```

```
private void ReceiveMessage()
        {
            //netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            string JSONmsg = " ";
            int i;


            using (netStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int numBytesRead;
                    while ((numBytesRead = netStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        ms.Read(buffer, 0, numBytesRead);
                    }
                    JSONmsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
                    DisplayMessage(JSONmsg);
                }
            }

        }
```

```
private void DisplayMessage(string JSONmsg)
        {
            if (dataTelemetryInfo.InvokeRequired)
            {
                object[] args = new object[] { JSONmsg };
                this.Invoke(new StringArg(DisplayMessage), args);  //StringArg is a delegate with a string as a parameter       
            }
            else
            {
                lblTest.Text += JSONmsg;

                telemetryInfo = serializer.Deserialize<TelemetryUpdate>(JSONmsg);

                dataTelemetryInfo.Rows.Add(telemetryInfo.Altitude.ToString(), telemetryInfo.ElevatorPitch.ToString(), telemetryInfo.Pitch.ToString(),
               telemetryInfo.Speed.ToString(), telemetryInfo.Throttle.ToString(), telemetryInfo.VerticalSpeed.ToString(),
               telemetryInfo.WarningCode.ToString());  

            }
        }
```

Once I connect the programs, and I click on the Listen button of my GUI (which starts the "start()" method), nothing changes and my datagridview isn't updated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you call `messageInThread.Start();` somewhere in your code?

Comment: I did (forgot to add it in the post), but it still does not work and my data grid does not update.

Comment: You read from network stream into `byte[] buffer`, then read from the empty memory stream into the same `buffer` ? Did you mean ms.Write() ?

Comment: @OguzOzgul Yes, thank you. I made a mistake right here. I changed it to write to the buffer. However, it still doesn't display the message onto my datagridview. Could it be because of the way the object parameters are ordered (because the object parameters are 7)? For example, if the flight Sim is sending me an object that starts with the Throttle as a parameter but my GUI's TelemetryUpdate starts with the Altitude.

Comment: Are you sure the text stream is `ASCII` and not `UTF8` or another format?

Comment: Oh Deutch! You must debug your source code and see where the problem is.

Comment: @FrankNielsen Thank you for the idea. I just asked and I was told that the program does use ASCII and not another format.

Comment: @OguzOzgul You're right. I'm still new to programming and doing a crash course at university in C#. I wish I chose something else at this point haha. The debugger just normally stopped at the message thread (like it was never invoked?). I'll figure it out, thanks again for your help.

Comment: @HellKnight - Please don't annotate questions with solutions or ask follow on questions. Please post thank yous in comments and ask brand new questions if you have a follow up.

Comment: The network stream from `tcpClient.GetStream()` is blocking on `Read` until something is send from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ReceiveMessage` to:

```
private void ReceiveMessage()
        {
            //netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            string JSONmsg = " ";
            int i;


            using (netStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int numBytesRead;
                    while ((numBytesRead = netStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, numBytesRead);
                    }
                    JSONmsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                    DisplayMessage(JSONmsg);
                }
            }

        }
```

You must `.Write` to your `MemoryStream`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just changed it. The datagridview is still not displaying anything sent from the Flight Simulator but at least I finally understand why I should write to the memory stream.